# Cantor-Lebesgue Functions

Tags: analysis

Show that there is a continuous, strictly increasing function on the interval [0, 1] that maps a set of positive measure onto a set of measure zero.

Is it enough to prove that a strictly increasing function that is defined on an interval has a continuous inverse? Will that be a good starting point to prove?